# ghci special case for Applicative?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghci, applicative

In ghci:

```
λ> :t (pure 1)
(pure 1) :: (Applicative f, Num a) => f a
λ> show (pure 1)

<interactive>:1:1:
    No instance for (Show (f0 a0))
      arising from a use of `show'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (f0 a0))
    In the expression: show (pure 1)
    In an equation for `it': it = show (pure 1)
λ> pure 1
1
```

Does this mean that ghci execute Applicative and displays the result, just like `IO`?

Note that `pure ()` and `pure (+1)` don't print anything.

Comment: `show (pure 1 :: [Int])` works.  `show (pure 1 :: Maybe Integer)` too. there was no defaulting there, so ghci didn't know which types to choose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get the same behaviour if you use `return` instead of `pure`. To find out what to do, ghci must choose a type for the given expression. ghci's defaulting rules are such that absent other constraints, it chooses `IO` for an `Applicative` or `Monad` instance. Thus it interprets `pure 1` as an expression of type `IO Integer`. Expressions of type `IO a` entered at the prompt are executed and their results are printed, if 1. `a` has a `Show` instance and 2. `a` is not `()`. Thus entering `pure 1` at the prompt results in

```
v <- return (1 :: Integer)
print v
return v
```

being executed (and the magic variable `it` bound to the returned `v`). For `pure ()`, the special case applies since `()` is considered uninteresting, thus only `return ()` is executed and `it` bound to `()`, for `pure (+1)`, a function is returned, there's no `Show` instance for functions in scope, so nothing is printed. However,

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :m +Text.Show.Functions
Prelude Control.Applicative Text.Show.Functions> pure (+1)
<function>
it :: Integer -> Integer
Prelude Control.Applicative Text.Show.Functions> it 3
4
it :: Integer
```

with a `Show` instance for functions in scope, it gets printed (not that it's informative), and the function can then be used (the latter is independent of a `Show` instance being in scope, of course).

Comment: I've just realized that `instance Applicative IO`. So it also allows `pure 1 >>= \it -> print it` to work.  I've just learned about the `Text.Show.Functions` module.  I've always wondered why functions were not showable by default.

Comment: Here is one more example of using Applicative, Functor and IO: `pure (+1) <*> fmap (read :: String -> Int) getLine`

Comment: is it possible to indicate the type ghci should default to, for a type for a custom typeclass?